# Where all controller frontnames are stored?

Tags: controllers

Suppose I've action URL `abc/index/save` and frontname `abc` is defined in my config file. When I hit `abc/index/save` it calls my action method. Where all frontname informations are stored? Does it searches for the given frontnames through config.xml file of all Magento modules? I just wanted to know about the flow, if it searches for the frontname through config file of all modules then it might take some time to search for the given one and load contents accordingly?

Comment: magento does not save all frontend in db

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the frontnames all come from a merged `config.xml` file.

Yes, the initial scanning of this takes some time.  However, after loading and merging all the config.xml files -- Magento caches the results.  This means it's only the **first** loading of the configuration files that's slow.  Subsequent lookups are fast.

If you're interested in "the flow", you might find two of my Magento article series interesting.

- [In Depth Magento Dispatch](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#dispatch)
- [The Magento Config Revisited](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#magento_config)

These articles cover, in depth, how Magento bootstraps itself and handles a request.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed in the configuration of all the separate modules. However this XML tree is cached, the loading doesn't take that long.

Take a look at initModulesCache(), from either Mage it Mage_Config.